# Does os.remove() {Python 3} permanently deletes the specified file or is a residue file left in my HDD?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so I am running a program which will create 1000 files(each of around 40kb) but then I need to delete those so I was using os.remove() but was wandering whether after doing so is it deleting those 1000 × 40kb space because I need to create those 1000 files for many times and if those 40kbs keep stacking up then my hdd might get filled up with junk and I don't want that because there is not much space left.

Comment: You can think of a file system as a list of filenames that point to sections of the hard drive. For example you have a list which might contain an item like `/some/path/myfile.txt` -> bytes 264210 to 264333 on hard drive 1. When you `os.remove('/some/path/myfile.txt')`, you're just deleting the item in the list. The data stored on bytes 264210 to 264333 on hard drive 1 is not modified and still contains the data, until some other file is created that overwrites that old data. And even then, there's special equipment that can sometimes figure out what was stored there before it was overwritten.

Comment: This is OS and filesystem dependent, but generally it's gone

Comment: It's permanent.  But as @Boris commented, most of the file might be recoverable if you know how to use a microscope.

Comment: Okay so I am running a program which will create 1000 files(each of around 40kb) but then I need to delete those so I was using os.remove() but was wandering whether after doing so is it deleting those 1000 × 40kb space because I need to create those 1000 files for many times and if those 40kbs keep stacking up then my hdd might get filled up with junk and I don't want that because there is not much space left.

Comment: When a file is removed the space is marked as reusable, so you don't have to worry about running out of room.  However there are utilities that can recover files if the disk sectors haven't been reused yet.

Comment: So my files will suddenly pop back?

Comment: @DhimanDutta no, `os.remove` deletes files. After you delete a file it's not going to pop back. The space on your hard drive is marked as free and new files will be written to it. In my comment I thought you were asking how to delete a file in such a way that it would be physically impossible to recover the data. If you just need to delete files, you can use `os.remove`.